# String contains

Tags: c#

Добрый день, как можно проверить наличие слова из массива в строке?
например:

```
string dwords = "h|w|l|o";
boolean contains = "Hello World".Contains(dwords.split("|"));
```

?

Comment: Циклом, например?

Comment: Ещё варианты?

Comment: @Hilgert любые другие варианты тоже будут явно или неявно использовать цикл

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проверка содержит ли символ из строки

```
 string dwords = "h|w|l|o";
    var contains = "Hello World".Any(dwords.Contains);
```

Проверка содержит ли строка строку из массива

```
var dwords = new string[] {"Hello","world"};
var contains = "Hello world".Split(' ').Any(dwords.Contains);
```